# jQuery load() fails in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

My client is running relatively current versions of IE (7, 8, 9)

I have narrowed the problem down to 1 line of jQuery that is working in every browser I have tested except the IE family:

```
$('#ContactsListTable').load('/ContactList/TicketNumber/'+ticketNumber+'/format/html');
```

**My question**: why does this line work in all modern browsers except IE family.  That is the only line in my modal dialog (success event), that falls between a console.log('success' - stating that the contact form was successfully posted), and the dialog box that closes which also executes successfully.

What needs to be changed in order for it to work in IE as well?

(Moral of the story, always cross browser test EVERTYHING before you hand it to the client. )

Comment: Does the relative URL resolve correctly? Are you using a base tag or something on your page that would mess with relative URLs? Try putting the URL on your page as a link and see if it works... other than that, I've never had a problem with jQuery load in IE.

Comment: Lesson learned? Always test your apps in all major browsers. That includes IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Can you post a jsfiddle? There might be issues with your HTML as well.

Comment: This question is 92% dramatics and grandeur and only 8% question.  You could have asked the same thing in three or four sentences and spared us your rookie mistake of not cross browser testing.

Comment: Loved your depiction. +1 for that. You really should put it in your blog.

Comment: I decided to try and save him from himself with my edit. It may be too late though.

Comment: c'mon, the post/story was for fun, I am not 13, it was supposed to give everyone a laugh, regardless, @BrandonBoone yes the link works, note it works in firefox, safari (and just tested working in chrome).

Comment: @flaviotsf normally I do, this was supposed to be a quick simple page, my mistake for not cross browser testing

Comment: everyone else, relax, if ya didn't want to read it, carry on, lots of questions here to answer, it was meant to be entertaining!  Chill!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some digging, I found other people experiencing the same problem in IE only. Apparently IE strictly validates the HTML returned, whereas most other browsers will accept most any HTML. For example, one forum post mentioned an unclosed `<ul>` element in the HTML, which Firefox and Safari gladly accepted but IE barfed on.

Comment: @Larry: Absolutely, this is one case where IE does the right thing.

Comment: Thank you for an answer to the question, sadly I do have to agree with @larrylustig because in reality, there should be some control on malformed HTML, and to all who commented in the original post (pre-edit), I am still shocked at the negative response in a post that was meant to add a bit of humor to your lives.  My past posts have all been to the point and responses were appreciated, my future questions and answers will also be to the point and I will refrain from dramatic humor attempts.  Point taken!  Peace and happy coding.

Comment: @William just to clarify, are you suggesting an error in the HTML received from the .load()?  I will go back and check that again.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, based on what I've read, if the HTML received from the `load()` function call is malformed, IE will reject it and the function will fail.